# How to convert AQMP message buffer into JSON object when using node.js amqp module?

Tags: node.js, type-conversion, node-amqp

I am using node.js amqp module for reading messages from a queue. The following is the callback that is invoked when there is a message available on the queue:

```
function onMessage(message, headers, deliveryInfo)
{
    console.log(message); //This prints buffer
    //how to convert message (which I expect to be JSON) into a JSON object.
    //Also how to get the JSON string from the 'message' which seems to be a buffer
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

message.data.toString() returned the appropriate JSON string.

Answer (score 14):

If you receive a Buffer that contains JSON, then you'll need to convert it to a string to output something meaningful to the console:

```
console.log(message.toString())
```

If you want to convert that string to a full JavaScript object, then just parse the JSON:

```
var res = JSON.parse(message.toString())
```

*Edit:* node-amqp seems to be able to send directly JavaScript objects (see [here](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp/blob/master/README.md#exchangepublishroutingkey-message-options-callback)), you shouldn't be receiving buffers but instead JavaScript objects... Check how you send your messages.

Comment: When I set message to {"name":"anand"} from rabbitmq console, console.log(message.toString()) is printing [object Object].

Comment: That's normal, see [`Object.toString()`'s documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString). If you see that, then you received a standard javascript object (most likely `{name: "anand"}`) and not a Buffer. What does `console.log(message)` outputs then?

Comment: Well, the messages aren't necessarily *sent* from node-amqp :)

Comment: in server side: ch.sendToQueue(req.properties.replyTo,
          new Buffer( JSON.stringify( fResult) ),
          {correlationId: req.properties.correlationId});        so ,client side :const jsonResult = JSON.parse(result.content) ; //https://github.com/no7dw/rabbitmq-demo/blob/master/client_example.js